# How to make bullets appear in a blender animation?

Tags: visibility

I want to make an animation where a plane shoots many bullets at another one.
I don't want to create all bullets and make them invisible since that will make the window laggy and increase render time to near infinity.
I want a bullet to not exist until a specific point and then at a specific frame it exists and then at another frame it's nonexistent again.

I couldn't try anything since nobody ever had a tutorial on this.

Comment: Hello, could you add a little more information about your setup, what you have so far, what you have tried, why you think your solution will make your window laggy,... ?

Comment: If you create instances of one bullet instead of making them all single unrelated objects, then the system load won't be that high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try out a particle system...   On the target aircraft, attach a Force that is negative (like -20,000).  You can create a prototype bullet and in the Particle Rendering, Render as OBJECT, with your prototype object selected as the instance object.  In Field Weights, you might change the Gravity to zero.

[image]

[image]

I even happened to have a cruddy airplane model sitting around, so here's a [image]

(I just replaced my file with an update, as the "bullets" weren't rendering. Had to change Particle Source to Emit from FACES)

Comment: very nice, i like it!

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Comment: @entertainmentanimations -- consider marking this as a solution (checkbox), so my creds get a bump for my effort.